# VBA Excel 2-Dimensional Arrays

Tags: excel, vba, multidimensional-array

I was trying to find out how to declare a 2-Dimensional array but all of the examples I have found so far are declared with set integers.  I'm trying to create a program that will utilize two 2-Dimensional arrays and then perform simple operations on those arrays (such as finding difference or percent).  The arrays are populated by numbers in Excel sheets (one set of numbers is on Sheet1 and another set is on Sheet2, both sets have the same number of rows and columns).

Since I don't know how many rows or columns there are I was going to use variables.

```
Dim s1excel As Worksheet
Dim s2excel As Worksheet
Dim s3excel As Worksheet
Dim firstSheetName As String
Dim secondSheetName As String
Dim totalRow As Integer
Dim totalCol As Integer
Dim iRow As Integer
Dim iCol As Integer

Set s1excel = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

' Open the "Raw_Data" workbook
Set wbs = Workbooks.Open(file_path & data_title)
wbs.Activate
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(firstSheetName).Select
Set s2excel = wbs.ActiveSheet

' Find totalRow, totalColumn (assumes there's values in Column A and Row 1 with no blanks)
totalRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
totalCol = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column

Dim s2Array(totalRow, totalCol)
Dim s3Array(totalRow, totalCol)

For iRow = 1 To totalRow
    For iCol = 1 To totalCol
        s2Array(iRow, iCol) = Cells(iRow, iCol)
    Next iCol
Next iRow

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(secondSheetName).Select
Set s3excel = wbs.ActiveSheet

For iRow = 1 To totalRow
    For iCol = 1 To totalCol
        s3Array(iRow, iCol) = Cells(iRow, iCol)
    Next iCol
Next iRow
```

When I attempt to run this I get a compile-time error at the `Dim s2Array(totalRow, totalCol)` saying that a constant expression is required. The same error occurs if I change it to `Dim s2Array(1 To totalRow, 1 To totalCol)`.  Since I don't know what the dimensions are from the get go I can't declare it like `Dim s2Array(1, 1)` because then I'll get an out-of-bounds exception.

Thank you,

Jesse Smothermon

Comment: use variant arrays as per iDevlop's answer.  They were made for Ranges in Excel.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In fact I would not use any REDIM, nor a loop for transferring data from sheet to array:

```
dim arOne()
arOne = range("A2:F1000")
```

or even

```
arOne = range("A2").CurrentRegion
```

and that's it, your array is filled much faster then with a loop, no redim.

Comment: +1 That's a better way to do it I agree. I naively just dealt with the syntax error.

Comment: This is the best way, it should be pointed out that the dim statement uses Variant by default.

Comment: I don't know what the dimensions are before the macro starts to run.  Thank you for replying

Comment: Tested it on mine and it at least did the same thing as ReDim and it did seem faster.  Quick question, could I use this CurrentRegion to fill a specific space with an array?  So it might look like Range("A2").CurrentRegion = arTwo where arTwo is some array.  Thanks

Comment: I read a little more on CurrentRegion, am I correct that it just highlights the region or does it store values into the array (here wanted a 2-dimensional array)?

Comment: CurrentRegion extends the range until it finds an empty row and an empty column. It's the "=" sign that assigns the range values into the array.

Comment: @iDevlop Once I set the values into the arrays how do I perform operations on them?  So here s2Array has one set of values, s3Array has another set and answerArray will be the difference between those arrays.  s2Array and s3Array are located in different excel sheets.  I tried to do answerArray = s2Array - s3Array but get a Type mismatch.  Thank you

Comment: For that, you will have to use a double imbricated loop, like in your original post. No shortcuts here, alas.

Comment: Sorry that this isn't in proper form... but here's my code for trying to subtract the values in one array from another. For iRow = 1 To totalRow
            For iCol = 1 To totalCol
                answerArray(iRow, iCol) = s2Array(iRow, iCol) - s3Array(iRow, iCol)
            Next iCol
        Next iRow
answerArray has blank values all the way through.  Can you tell what's wrong with it?  Thank you

Answer (score 8):

You need `ReDim`:

```
m = 5
n = 8
Dim my_array()
ReDim my_array(1 To m, 1 To n)
For i = 1 To m
  For j = 1 To n
    my_array(i, j) = i * j
  Next
Next

For i = 1 To m
  For j = 1 To n
    Cells(i, j) = my_array(i, j)
  Next
Next
```

---

As others have pointed out, your actual problem would be better solved with ranges. You could try something like this:

```
Dim r1 As Range
Dim r2 As Range
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet

Set ws1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")
totalRow = ws1.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
totalCol = ws1.Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column

Set r1 = ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(1, 1), ws1.Cells(totalRow, totalCol))
Set r2 = ws2.Range(ws2.Cells(1, 1), ws2.Cells(totalRow, totalCol))
r2.Value = r1.Value
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems like it's working but I can't really tell because I can't actually see what's in there.  Do you know how to print the values into Cells?  Here's what I have so far:
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(firstSheetName).Copy Before:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(firstSheetName)
    
    For iRow = 1 To totalRow
        For iCol = 1 To totalCol
            ActiveSheet.Cells(iRow, iCol) = answerArray(iRow, iCol)
        Next iCol
    Next iRow
But this doesn't actually output anything

Comment: @Jesse Try my edit, stuff if into code in an empty worksheet and hit F5!

Comment: @David Got kind of a weird error.  My test grid goes from 1 to 324, dimensions being 9 by 36 (with the second grid going from 324 to 1).  I change your code strictly to fit my code so nothing major except names differ.  So far it seems to just copy my first grid over and then has a message box that says "Cannot perform requested operation".  Thanks

Comment: @Jesse Well I can't guess what cause that, must be something wrong in your code. Anyway, you should do it @iDevelop's way, it will be much easier and quicker!

Comment: @Jesse For what it's worth, I've updated my answer to include a range based version.

Comment: I figured out what the problem was.... when I was populating the arrays i just used "Cells" instead of "ActiveSheet.Cells".  I guess when you just use Cells it looks at the sheet where the macro button is located

Comment: Do you know how to print the values into Cells?  Er, ye, I do. You saw the code that populates a 2-Dimensional array variant as varX - range.value ? If you can define a range of the same dimensions, range.value = varArrayX populates your range *in one 'hit to the sheet' instead of several hundred separate write-to-cell operations. I'll see if I can post some boilerplate code I wrote that encapsulates the process...

Answer (score 5):

Here's **A generic VBA Array To Range function** that writes an array to the sheet in a single 'hit' to the sheet. This is *much* faster than writing the data into the sheet one cell at a time in loops for the rows and columns... However, there's some housekeeping to do, as you must specify the size of the target range correctly.

This 'housekeeping' looks like a lot of work and it's probably rather slow: but this is 'last mile' code to write to the sheet, and *everything* is faster than writing to the worksheet. Or at least, so much faster that it's effectively instantaneous, compared with a read or write to the worksheet, even in VBA, and you should do everything you possibly can in code before you hit the sheet.

A major component of this is error-trapping that I used to see turning up everywhere . I hate repetitive coding: I've coded it all here, and - hopefully - you'll never have to write it again.

**A VBA 'Array to Range' function**

```
Public Sub ArrayToRange(rngTarget As Excel.Range, InputArray As Variant)
' Write an array to an Excel range in a single 'hit' to the sheet
' InputArray must be a 2-Dimensional structure of the form Variant(Rows, Columns)

' The target range is resized automatically to the dimensions of the array, with
' the top left cell used as the start point.

' This subroutine saves repetitive coding for a common VBA and Excel task.

' If you think you won't need the code that works around common errors (long strings
' and objects in the array, etc) then feel free to comment them out.

On Error Resume Next

'
' Author: Nigel Heffernan
' HTTP://Excellerando.blogspot.com
'
' This code is in te public domain: take care to mark it clearly, and segregate
' it from proprietary code if you intend to assert intellectual property rights
' or impose commercial confidentiality restrictions on that proprietary code

Dim rngOutput As Excel.Range

Dim iRowCount   As Long
Dim iColCount   As Long
Dim iRow        As Long
Dim iCol        As Long
Dim arrTemp     As Variant
Dim iDimensions As Integer

Dim iRowOffset  As Long
Dim iColOffset  As Long
Dim iStart      As Long


Application.EnableEvents = False
If rngTarget.Cells.Count > 1 Then
    rngTarget.ClearContents
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True

If IsEmpty(InputArray) Then
    Exit Sub
End If


If TypeName(InputArray) = "Range" Then
    InputArray = InputArray.Value
End If

' Is it actually an array? IsArray is sadly broken so...
If Not InStr(TypeName(InputArray), "(") Then
    rngTarget.Cells(1, 1).Value2 = InputArray
    Exit Sub
End If


iDimensions = ArrayDimensions(InputArray)

If iDimensions < 1 Then

    rngTarget.Value = CStr(InputArray)

ElseIf iDimensions = 1 Then

    iRowCount = UBound(InputArray) - LBound(InputArray)
    iStart = LBound(InputArray)
    iColCount = 1

    If iRowCount > (655354 - rngTarget.Row) Then
        iRowCount = 655354 + iStart - rngTarget.Row
        ReDim Preserve InputArray(iStart To iRowCount)
    End If

    iRowCount = UBound(InputArray) - LBound(InputArray)
    iColCount = 1

    ' It's a vector. Yes, I asked for a 2-Dimensional array. But I'm feeling generous.
    ' By convention, a vector is presented in Excel as an arry of 1 to n rows and 1 column.
    ReDim arrTemp(LBound(InputArray, 1) To UBound(InputArray, 1), 1 To 1)
    For iRow = LBound(InputArray, 1) To UBound(InputArray, 1)
        arrTemp(iRow, 1) = InputArray(iRow)
    Next

    With rngTarget.Worksheet
        Set rngOutput = .Range(rngTarget.Cells(1, 1), rngTarget.Cells(iRowCount + 1, iColCount))
        rngOutput.Value2 = arrTemp
        Set rngTarget = rngOutput
    End With

    Erase arrTemp

ElseIf iDimensions = 2 Then

    iRowCount = UBound(InputArray, 1) - LBound(InputArray, 1)
    iColCount = UBound(InputArray, 2) - LBound(InputArray, 2)

    iStart = LBound(InputArray, 1)

    If iRowCount > (65534 - rngTarget.Row) Then
        iRowCount = 65534 - rngTarget.Row
        InputArray = ArrayTranspose(InputArray)
        ReDim Preserve InputArray(LBound(InputArray, 1) To UBound(InputArray, 1), iStart To iRowCount)
        InputArray = ArrayTranspose(InputArray)
    End If


    iStart = LBound(InputArray, 2)
    If iColCount > (254 - rngTarget.Column) Then
        ReDim Preserve InputArray(LBound(InputArray, 1) To UBound(InputArray, 1), iStart To iColCount)
    End If



    With rngTarget.Worksheet

        Set rngOutput = .Range(rngTarget.Cells(1, 1), rngTarget.Cells(iRowCount + 1, iColCount + 1))

        Err.Clear
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        rngOutput.Value2 = InputArray
        Application.EnableEvents = True

        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            For iRow = LBound(InputArray, 1) To UBound(InputArray, 1)
                For iCol = LBound(InputArray, 2) To UBound(InputArray, 2)
                    If IsNumeric(InputArray(iRow, iCol)) Then
                        ' no action
                    Else
                        InputArray(iRow, iCol) = "" & InputArray(iRow, iCol)
                        InputArray(iRow, iCol) = Trim(InputArray(iRow, iCol))
                    End If
                Next iCol
            Next iRow
            Err.Clear
            rngOutput.Formula = InputArray
        End If 'err<>0

        If Err <> 0 Then
            For iRow = LBound(InputArray, 1) To UBound(InputArray, 1)
                For iCol = LBound(InputArray, 2) To UBound(InputArray, 2)
                    If IsNumeric(InputArray(iRow, iCol)) Then
                        ' no action
                    Else
                        If Left(InputArray(iRow, iCol), 1) = "=" Then
                            InputArray(iRow, iCol) = "'" & InputArray(iRow, iCol)
                        End If
                        If Left(InputArray(iRow, iCol), 1) = "+" Then
                            InputArray(iRow, iCol) = "'" & InputArray(iRow, iCol)
                        End If
                        If Left(InputArray(iRow, iCol), 1) = "*" Then
                            InputArray(iRow, iCol) = "'" & InputArray(iRow, iCol)
                        End If
                    End If
                Next iCol
            Next iRow
            Err.Clear
            rngOutput.Value2 = InputArray
        End If 'err<>0

        If Err <> 0 Then
            For iRow = LBound(InputArray, 1) To UBound(InputArray, 1)
                For iCol = LBound(InputArray, 2) To UBound(InputArray, 2)

                    If IsObject(InputArray(iRow, iCol)) Then
                        InputArray(iRow, iCol) = "[OBJECT] " & TypeName(InputArray(iRow, iCol))
                    ElseIf IsArray(InputArray(iRow, iCol)) Then
                        InputArray(iRow, iCol) = Split(InputArray(iRow, iCol), ",")
                    ElseIf IsNumeric(InputArray(iRow, iCol)) Then
                        ' no action
                    Else
                        InputArray(iRow, iCol) = "" & InputArray(iRow, iCol)
                        If Len(InputArray(iRow, iCol)) > 255 Then
                            ' Block-write operations fail on strings exceeding 255 chars. You *have*
                            ' to go back and check, and write this masterpiece one cell at a time...
                            InputArray(iRow, iCol) = Left(Trim(InputArray(iRow, iCol)), 255)
                        End If
                    End If
                Next iCol
            Next iRow
            Err.Clear
            rngOutput.Text = InputArray
        End If 'err<>0

        If Err <> 0 Then
            Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
            iRowOffset = LBound(InputArray, 1) - 1
            iColOffset = LBound(InputArray, 2) - 1
            For iRow = 1 To iRowCount
                If iRow Mod 100 = 0 Then
                    Application.StatusBar = "Filling range... " & CInt(100# * iRow / iRowCount) & "%"
                End If
                For iCol = 1 To iColCount
                    rngOutput.Cells(iRow, iCol) = InputArray(iRow + iRowOffset, iCol + iColOffset)
                Next iCol
            Next iRow
            Application.StatusBar = False
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True


        End If 'err<>0


        Set rngTarget = rngOutput   ' resizes the range This is useful, *most* of the time

    End With

End If

End Sub
```

**You will need the source for ArrayDimensions:**

This API declaration is required in the module header:

```
Private Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" _
                   (Destination As Any, _
                    Source As Any, _
                    ByVal Length As Long)
```

...And here's the function itself:

```
Private Function ArrayDimensions(arr As Variant) As Integer
  '-----------------------------------------------------------------
  ' will return:
  ' -1 if not an array
  ' 0  if an un-dimmed array
  ' 1  or more indicating the number of dimensions of a dimmed array
  '-----------------------------------------------------------------


  ' Retrieved from Chris Rae's VBA Code Archive - http://chrisrae.com/vba
  ' Code written by Chris Rae, 25/5/00

  ' Originally published by R. B. Smissaert.
  ' Additional credits to Bob Phillips, Rick Rothstein, and Thomas Eyde on VB2TheMax

  Dim ptr As Long
  Dim vType As Integer

  Const VT_BYREF = &H4000&

  'get the real VarType of the argument
  'this is similar to VarType(), but returns also the VT_BYREF bit
  CopyMemory vType, arr, 2

  'exit if not an array
  If (vType And vbArray) = 0 Then
    ArrayDimensions = -1
    Exit Function
  End If

  'get the address of the SAFEARRAY descriptor
  'this is stored in the second half of the
  'Variant parameter that has received the array
  CopyMemory ptr, ByVal VarPtr(arr) + 8, 4

  'see whether the routine was passed a Variant
  'that contains an array, rather than directly an array
  'in the former case ptr already points to the SA structure.
  'Thanks to Monte Hansen for this fix

  If (vType And VT_BYREF) Then
    ' ptr is a pointer to a pointer
    CopyMemory ptr, ByVal ptr, 4
  End If

  'get the address of the SAFEARRAY structure
  'this is stored in the descriptor

  'get the first word of the SAFEARRAY structure
  'which holds the number of dimensions
  '...but first check that saAddr is non-zero, otherwise
  'this routine bombs when the array is uninitialized

  If ptr Then
    CopyMemory ArrayDimensions, ByVal ptr, 2
  End If

End Function
```

Also: I would advise you to keep that declaration private. If you must make it a public Sub in another module, insert the `Option Private Module` statement in the module header. You really don't want your users calling any function with CopyMemoryoperations and pointer arithmetic.

Comment: +1 for saying "you should do everything you possibly can before hitting the sheet" and +1 for having the most mega-ginormous post i have ever seen on SO.. at least in the VBA section.

Comment: @iDevlop   ...Yep, **all that stuff**. Partly, this is VBA not being a concise language; mostly, we're not passing parameters to a well-defined function written by a developer, we're interacting with a user interface - a grid that can contain any data type and all manner of errors - which demands extensive defensive coding.

Comment: @Nile: I was joking. I don't reaaly see the added value compared to the "one line solution" I gave http://stackoverflow.com/a/5252452/78522

Comment: @iDevlop - If you only ever do it once, the added value is negative. If you develop over a hundred tactical tools a year, dumping data into ranges anywhere and everywhere, **and you've got to support them**  the value of code with the resilience built in is considerable. The most important productivity metric for a tactical developer isn't line output, it's the continuing workload per line of code.

Answer (score 2):

For this example you will need to create your own type, that would be an array. Then you create a bigger array which elements are of type you have just created.

To run my example you will need to fill columns **A** and **B** in **Sheet1** with some values. Then run **test()**. It will read first **two rows** and add the values to the **BigArr**. Then it will check how many rows of data you have and read them all, from the place it has stopped reading, i.e., 3rd row.

Tested in Excel 2007.

```
Option Explicit
Private Type SmallArr
  Elt() As Variant
End Type

Sub test()
    Dim x As Long, max_row As Long, y As Long
    '' Define big array as an array of small arrays
    Dim BigArr() As SmallArr
    y = 2
    ReDim Preserve BigArr(0 To y)
    For x = 0 To y
        ReDim Preserve BigArr(x).Elt(0 To 1)
        '' Take some test values
        BigArr(x).Elt(0) = Cells(x + 1, 1).Value
        BigArr(x).Elt(1) = Cells(x + 1, 2).Value
    Next x
    '' Write what has been read
    Debug.Print "BigArr size = " & UBound(BigArr) + 1
    For x = 0 To UBound(BigArr)
        Debug.Print BigArr(x).Elt(0) & " | " & BigArr(x).Elt(1)
    Next x
    '' Get the number of the last not empty row
    max_row = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    '' Change the size of the big array
    ReDim Preserve BigArr(0 To max_row)

    Debug.Print "new size of BigArr with old data = " & UBound(BigArr)
    '' Check haven't we lost any data
    For x = 0 To y
        Debug.Print BigArr(x).Elt(0) & " | " & BigArr(x).Elt(1)
    Next x

    For x = y To max_row
        '' We have to change the size of each Elt,
        '' because there are some new for,
        '' which the size has not been set, yet.
        ReDim Preserve BigArr(x).Elt(0 To 1)
        '' Take some test values
        BigArr(x).Elt(0) = Cells(x + 1, 1).Value
        BigArr(x).Elt(1) = Cells(x + 1, 2).Value
    Next x

    '' Check what we have read
    Debug.Print "BigArr size = " & UBound(BigArr) + 1
    For x = 0 To UBound(BigArr)
        Debug.Print BigArr(x).Elt(0) & " | " & BigArr(x).Elt(1)
    Next x

End Sub
```