# Is there a way to create a 2-dimensional array in VBA using Array function>

Tags: arrays, vba, type-2-dimension

I want to quickly create a 6X4 array of small integers.
For a small 1-dimensional array, I like to use something like

```
Dim MyArr()
MyArr = Array(1,2,3,4,5,6)
```

Is there a similar way to create a 2-D array?
I tried separating the rows with ; but

`MyArr = Array (1, 2, 3; 4, 5, 6)` is invalid.

I guess I'm being too lazy to set up the loops, but a one-line method would be *compact* and useful.

Comment: If you're using Excel, then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5252452/9245853).

Comment: `MyArr = [{1,2;3,4}]` at least in Excel

Comment: @TimWilliams ha! I always forget about using `Application.Evaluate` like this - that's actually answer-worthy, and exactly the compact form OP seems to be looking for.

Comment: I don't want to repeat the relatively unknown use of **`Application.Index`** to transform a *jagged array* via **double zero** arguments here, as I've answered it already at [Initialize a (2-)dim array in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24584088/how-to-initialize-a-multidimensional-array-variable-in-vba-for-excel/66969472#66969472); further readings [Some pecularities of `Application.Index()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51688593/excel-vba-insert-new-first-column-in-datafield-array-without-loops-or-api-call/51714153#51714153)

Comment: I wasn't aware of Application.Evaluate, or it's short cut, enclosing the expression in square brackets.  Thanks, Tim for the answer, and Mathieu for pointing out that it's a way of using Evaluate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Excel you can use `Application.Evaluate` (or the `[]` shortcut) and an array literal:

```
MyArr = [{1,2;3,4}]
```

Answer (score 4):

The `VBA._HiddenModule.Array` function has this signature:

```
Public Function Array(ParamArray ArgList() As Variant) As Variant
```

I'd guess it's basically just returning the `ParamArray` pointer, effectively turning an inline sequence of elements into a simple one-dimensional `Variant` array.

If that sequence of elements consists in elements that are themselves arrays, then you can have yourself a *jagged array*, or "array of arrays" - but not a 2D array:

```
Dim JaggedArray As Variant
JaggedArray = Array( _
    Array(1, 2, 3, 4), _
    Array(1, 2, 3, 4), _
    Array(1, 2, 3, 4), _
    Array(1, 2, 3, 4), _
    Array(1, 2, 3, 4), _
    Array(1, 2, 3, 4), _
)
```

You access its elements with successive subscripts:

```
Debug.Print JaggedArray(2)(3)
```

The biggest issue with that, is that you've turned *data* into *code*, and what's normally a good thing is to *separate* the data from the code.

If only there was a worksheet nearby to read the data from!

```
Dim twoDimensionalVariantArray As Variant
twoDimensionalVariantArray = Sheet1.Range("A1:D6").Value
```

Or better yet, use a named range:

```
twoDimensionalVariantArray = Sheet1.Range("ItemsSource").Value
```

Or an actual table:

```
twoDimensionalVariantArray = Sheet1.ListObjects("Table1").DataBodyRange.Value
```

All one-liners, no loop needed!

Given a range representing an area of two or more cells, `Range.Value` returns a 2D `Variant` array. Careful though, an array that came from a worksheet will always be 1-based so that indexes line up with row and column numbers (there no row or column 0 on a worksheet). Always use `LBound(theArray, dimension)` and `UBound(theArray, dimension)` to get the lower and upper boundaries of an array before you iterate it with a `For...Next` loop.

You access its elements with 2D subscripts:

```
Debug.Print twoDimensionalVariantArray(2, 3)
```

Comment: fyi Might be interested in my extension to the proposed jagged array solution via  an undocumented feature of `Application.Index()` as well as another way by **sequencing** via MS 365. @MathieuGuindon

Answer (score 2):

**A) Quick alternative via Excel/MS 365**

To quickly create a 2-dim array (with well defined steps) you could profit from the new `SEQUENCE()` function in *Excel for MS 365*:

```
    Dim MyArr As Variant
    MyArr = Application.Sequence(2, 3, 1, 1)
```

**Result**

```
    MyArr(1,1) = 1
    MyArr(1,2) = 2
    MyArr(1,3) = 3
    MyArr(2,1) = 4
    MyArr(2,2) = 5
    MyArr(2,3) = 6
```

**[Syntax](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sequence-function-57467a98-57e0-4817-9f14-2eb78519ca90)**

```
=SEQUENCE(rows,[columns],[start],[step])
```

Note: Any missing optional arguments will default to 1.

*So it would suffice to pass only arguments (2, 3) to the Sequence function in this example.*

---

**B) Addendum** regarding **`Application.Index()`**

As already commented you can profit also from an *undocumented* use of `Application.Index` to

> transform a ►**jagged array** via *double zero* arguments.

```
Sub Get2DimArray()
    Dim MyArr() As Variant
    'a) build array of arrays (aka as jagged array)
    MyArr = Array(Array(1, 2, 3), Array(4, 5, 6))
    'b) make it 2-dimensional
    MyArr = Application.Index(MyArr, 0, 0)
End Sub
```

- See [Initialize a (2-)dim array in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24584088/how-to-initialize-a-multidimensional-array-variable-in-vba-for-excel/66969472#66969472)
- A further SO post lists [Some unknown pecularities of `Application.Index()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51688593/excel-vba-insert-new-first-column-in-datafield-array-without-loops-or-api-call/51714153#51714153)